# Are page id's persistent across backups of the same Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I have downloaded my site and db to my localhost but the page id's have changed breaking my css. Is this normal?

Comment: Do you migrated your DB to localhost ?

Comment: Yes and also an ftp and they changed. Seems like styling based on id's is bad unless you know why they changed for me?

Comment: Try to update permalinks

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion but I have resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone sees this the issue was that the exported db was renamed and given a new prefix before importing locally. NOt sure why that caused the issue but importing the original unchanged db resolved it.